# Remove overlapping time intervals from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with time intervals

```
$timeslots = array('9:00-10:00','10:00-11:00','11:00-12:00','12:00-13:00','13:00-14:00','14:00-15:00','15:00-16:00','16:00-17:00','17:00-18:00','18:00-19:00','19:00-20:00','20:00-21:00');
```

now I have two-time intervals(dynamic)

```
$start="10:15";
$end="11:15";
```

Now I want to remove two-time intervals from an array ( 10:00 to 11:00 and 11:00 to 12:00 ),
but my current code not working correctly, where I am wrong? Here is my code

```
$key=array_search("10:15-11:15", $timeslots);
        unset($timeslots[$key]);
        $timeslotss=array_values($timeslots);
```

Comment: there is no value like `10:15-11:15` in array.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra: you are right , but i want if this value come between array values then that values should remove, actually i want to show only availiable time slots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$timeslots = array('9:00-10:00','10:00-11:00','11:00-12:00','12:00-13:00','13:00-14:00','14:00-15:00','15:00-16:00','16:00-17:00','17:00-18:00','18:00-19:00','19:00-20:00','20:00-21:00');

$start="10:15";
$end="11:15";
$starttime = strtotime($start);
$endtime = strtotime($end);
foreach($timeslots as $time){   
    $key = array_search($time, $timeslots);

    $t = explode('-',$time);
    if(($starttime >= strtotime($t[0]) && $starttime <= strtotime($t[1])) ||($endtime > strtotime($t[0]) && $endtime < strtotime($t[1]))){
        unset($timeslots[$key]);
    }

}
echo'<pre>';print_r($timeslots);
?>
```

Comment: Does not work with  `$start = "10:15"` and `$end = "12:15"`. I would expect the timeslot `11:00-12:00` to be removed because it is overlapping, but it is not removed.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Overlapping time slots can happen in these cases:

```
(1)   S-----E
         S------E

(2)   S-----E
   S-----E

(3)   S-----E
        S-E

(4)   S-----E
    S----------E
```

`S` is for start, `E` for end. Now we can conclude that for an overlapping timeframe **either the start or the end** of the dynamic slot needs to be between start and end of the compared slot (1-3) **or both the start and the end must be before/after** those of the compared slot (4).

Your code does not work because you're just comparing strings, and the string you look for is not included in the array. PHP does not know that your strings *are* time intervalls.

### Solution

The following code should solve your problem.
The main logic is in `TimeSlot::overlaps` where we compare two slots.
Then we use this method with `array_filter` to remove overlapping time slots.

```php
class TimeSlot
{

    private $start;

    private $end;


    public function __construct(string $start, string $end)
    {
        $this->start = new DateTime($start);
        $this->end = new DateTime($end);
    }


    public function overlaps(TimeSlot $that): bool
    {
        return $this->start >= $that->start && $this->start <= $that->end
            || $this->end >= $that->start && $this->end <= $that->end
            || $this->start < $that->start && $this->end > $that->end;
    }


    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->start->format('H:i')
            . '-'
            . $this->end->format('H:i');
    }
}


// Use the data from your example and other test cases
$dynamicSlot = new TimeSlot('10:15', '11:15');
// $dynamicSlot = new TimeSlot('11:00', '13:00');
// $dynamicSlot = new TimeSlot('15:15', '16:00');
// $dynamicSlot = new TimeSlot('10:15', '12:15');
$timeslots = [
    new TimeSlot('9:00', '10:00'),
    new TimeSlot('10:00', '11:00'),
    new TimeSlot('11:00', '12:00'),
    new TimeSlot('12:00', '13:00'),
    new TimeSlot('13:00', '14:00'),
    new TimeSlot('14:00', '15:00'),
    new TimeSlot('15:00', '16:00'),
    new TimeSlot('16:00', '17:00'),
    new TimeSlot('17:00', '18:00'),
    new TimeSlot('18:00', '19:00'),
    new TimeSlot('19:00', '20:00'),
    new TimeSlot('20:00', '21:00'),
];

// Remove overlapping slots
$filteredTimeSlots = array_filter(
    $timeslots,
    function (TimeSlot $current) use ($dynamicSlot) {
        return !$dynamicSlot->overlaps($current);
    }
);

// Echo result
foreach ($filteredTimeSlots as $slot) {
    echo $slot . '</br>';
}
```

For your dynamic slot `10:15-11:15` It will produce the following output:

```
12:00-13:00
13:00-14:00
14:00-15:00
15:00-16:00
16:00-17:00
17:00-18:00
18:00-19:00
19:00-20:00
20:00-21:00
```

Surely it could be done without a class, but I think it's cleaner this way.
Please not that this was a quick write so it lacks proper input validation (and of course a class should live in its own namespace in its own source file).

### Procedural version

Because you asked, here is another version without any classes:

```
<?php
$timeslots = [
    '9:00-10:00',
    '10:00-11:00',
    '11:00-12:00',
    '12:00-13:00',
    '13:00-14:00',
    '14:00-15:00',
    '15:00-16:00',
    '16:00-17:00',
    '17:00-18:00',
    '18:00-19:00',
    '19:00-20:00',
    '20:00-21:00',
];

$dynamicStart = mktime(10, 15);
$dynamicEnd = mktime(11, 15);

// $dynamicStart = mktime(11, 00);
// $dynamicEnd = mktime(13, 00);

// $dynamicStart = mktime(15, 15);
// $dynamicEnd = mktime(16, 00);

//$dynamicStart = mktime(10, 15);
//$dynamicEnd = mktime(12, 15);

foreach ($timeslots as $index => $slot) {
    list($curStart, $curEnd) = explode('-', $slot);
    $curStart = explode(':', $curStart);
    $curEnd = explode(':', $curEnd);
    $curStart = mktime($curStart[0], $curStart[1]);
    $curEnd = mktime($curEnd[0], $curEnd[1]);

    if ($dynamicStart >= $curStart && $dynamicStart <= $curEnd
        || $dynamicEnd >= $curStart && $dynamicEnd <= $curEnd
        || $dynamicStart < $curStart && $dynamicEnd > $curEnd) {
        unset($timeslots[$index]);
    }
}

print_r($timeslots);
```

Comment: can you modify your code , i just want to do without class

Comment: @AmitSharma I've updated my answer to include a version without class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeslots = array('9:00-10:00','10:00-11:00','11:00-12:00','12:00-13:00','13:00-14:00','14:00-15:00','15:00-16:00','16:00-17:00','17:00-18:00','18:00-19:00','19:00-20:00','20:00-21:00');
$start="10:15";
$end="11:15";

$result = findTime($timeslots, $start, $end);
print_r($result);

function findTime($timeslots, $start, $end)
{
    $startArr = explode(':', $start);
    $endArr = explode(':', $end);
    foreach($timeslots as &$time) {
        if (strpos($time, $startArr[0]) === 0) {
          $timeArr = explode('-', $time);
          $time = $timeArr[0] . '-' . implode(':', $startArr);
        }
        if (strpos($time, $endArr[0]) === 0) {
          $timeArr = explode('-', $time);
          $time = implode(':', $endArr) . '-' . $timeArr[1];
        }
    }
    return $timeslots;
}
```

This code works for your asked condition but it will not work when start=10:15,end=10:30. Although I have the code but do some logical stuff yourself.

Comment: your code not working correct because its showing following output which is wrong

[0] => 9:00-10:00
    [1] => 10:00-10:15
    [2] => 11:15-12:00
    [3] => 12:00-13:00
    [4] => 13:00-14:00
    [5] => 14:00-15:00
    [6] => 15:00-16:00
    [7] => 16:00-17:00
    [8] => 17:00-18:00
    [9] => 18:00-19:00
    [10] => 19:00-20:00
    [11] => 20:00-21:00

Comment: Then what output are you expecting, I removed the start and end time from timeslots

Comment: but please dont change time interval/array values ( i want one hour slot), i just want to remove 10:00 to 11:00 and 11:00 to 12:00 because it comes between my dynamic slot ( 10:15 to 11:15) , simple